# Angular NGRX - naming the store/app-instance for Redux-Devtools

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am having trouble with Redux-Devtools plugin (for multiple browsers). So many websites use the Redux pattern that my own application often gets unselected. Does anyone know how how to name the store, so the plugin doesnt show 14/ngrx-store-somehash but the name of my app as the selected instance?

Comment: It appears to be internal to the [`DevtoolsExtension` class](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools/blob/v3.2.4/src/extension.ts#L35-L56). I guess you could extend it and inject your extended class.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store-devtools/src/config.ts) it has been added the parameter to configure store name with configuration option and it can be used like this:

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 5, name: "Yout custom store name here" }),
```

Today in production version (4.1.1) it is not yet available but you can download the git version if you want to use it.